# Ошибка FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'None'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qstackedwidget

Есть код приложения, состоящего из 4-х страниц, и я хочу вставить калькулятор, найденный на GitHub в 2 страницу.

Однако у меня появляется ошибка

> **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'None'**,

хотя все нужные файлы вроде находятся в одной директории, и я не понимаю как мне исправить эту ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста.

Скрин ошибки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот основной код, в который надо вставить калькулятор (часть кода я сделал в виде комментариев, дабы вы могли включить его):

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import os
import random
import logging.config 
import requests
import json
import datetime


from PyQt5.uic import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QTranslator, QLocale, QLibraryInfo
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from ext import *

from main import App                              # +++
from leoWidget import Example
from part_1 import Main
from Calculator import Calculator
from leoWidget import Example
from app_modules.views import AppView                     # +++
from app_modules.controller import AppController          # +++
from app_modules import widget_styles

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setWindowTitle('Unapp')
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(845,535))

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
# Content horizontalLayout_2 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)


        
        #Кнопка с домиком(главной страницей)                                 
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('дом.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
                
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Кнопка с заметками
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('калькулятор.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
       
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)

        #кнопка с калькулятором
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('заметка1.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))


        #Кнопка с текстовым редактором
        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('папочка.png'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))


        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

               
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 535))


        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
#1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        fontleo = QFont('Century Gothic', 25, QFont.Bold)
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
#Виджет с пожеланиями
        #self.leo = Example()
        
        
        #self.leo.setParent(self.page_1)






#календарь
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 380))
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(Calendar_StyleSheet)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)


        #self.main = App()

        #self.main.w_root.setParent(self.page_1)
        #self.main.w_root.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430,0,345,153))
        

        #self.main.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 165))
        #self.main.move(455,0)
        

        
        
        
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setKerning(True)

        self.CAL = Calculator()
        self.window.setParent(self.page_2)



        

        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setStyleSheet('background-color: #121212;')
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        #Заметки
        #self.view = AppView()

        
        # instance of the controller
        #self.ctrl = AppController(view=self.view)


        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)

        #self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.view)

        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        
        
        
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)

# page_4 verticalLayout_9
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
        #Текстовый редактор
        font2 = QtGui.QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(12)
        font2.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        #self.gg = Main()
        #self.gg.setFont(font2)


        
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               


        #self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.gg)




        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')


       


        
        
       
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        
# verticalLayout  centralwidget     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)    
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
# verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)

   


    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
 

Calendar_StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: #6d86a4;
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #6d86a4;
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;  
    image: none;              
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: #6d86a4; 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    logging.config.fileConfig('data/logger.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Иконка_Горы.png'))
    app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    
    PATH_LANGUAGE = r'C:/python2/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/translations/qtbase_ru.qm'
    translator = QTranslator(app1)
    translator.load(PATH_LANGUAGE, "ru_RU")
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот ссылка на файлы калькулятора: https://github.com/ivapop1/Calculator

Comment: Ну, так калькулятор без параметров вызываете. А по дефолту там путь `=None`.

Comment: А как вызвать его с параметрами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
...

#        self.CAL = Calculator()
        
        self.CAL = Calculator(
            title='Calculator App : Made by Rahul',
            parent=None,
            uiFile='form/ui_calculator.ui')
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.CAL.window)        
        
#        self.window.setParent(self.page_2)

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Появилась ошибка **TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>, 'QMainWindow'))**

Comment: @ivapop я не проверяю вашу логику. 
Вы спросили как вставить калькулятор. 
Что я делаю: 1. проверяю калькулятор - это рабочее приложение или нет. Не ахти, но 2 + 2 складывает правильно.
2. Запускаю пример, который вы привели в вопросе. Пример не запускается, 
так как куча модулей о которых я и не подозреваю. 
я комментирую все что вызывает ошибки, чтобы добраться до 
встраивания калькулятора. 3. Все калькулятор встроен и работает.